# Debug error InvocationTargetException?

Tags: android, youtube-api

```
08-05 00:25:13.320: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16232):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-05 00:25:13.320: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16232): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
08-05 00:25:13.320: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16232):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-05 00:25:13.320: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16232):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
08-05 00:25:13.320: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16232):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2678)
08-05 00:25:13.320: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16232):     ... 11 more
```

i keep getting these errors while running this method.

```
public void watchVideo(View view) {
    video.setVideoPath(current.url);
    video.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
    video.requestFocus();
    video.start();
}
```

Current is the YouTubeResult object from the Gdata api.

```
static YouTubeResult current;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just googling around, I have found this:

> Normally "java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException" occurs when
>   java compiler finds 2 different classes with same name in 2 different
>   packages. when u r importing both classes at a time and when you r
>   trying to create object of that class it throws
>   "java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException" exception .
>
> The solution is that when you are creating the object of the class use
>   package name also along with class name so that compiler knows what
>   class it has to use.

Also, try doing Project>Clean in Eclipse IDE. I hope I could be of some help. Cheers.

Comment: Nope, That didnt work. Still gives me that error at video.setVidePath()